# What's the correct way to CheckDeviceState in DirectX11?

Tags: directx-11, direct3d, ms-media-foundation, direct3d11

I have built the [DX11VideoRenderer sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/master/Samples/DX11VideoRenderer) (a replacement for EVR that uses DirectX11 instead of EVR's DirectX9), and it's working.  Problem is, it's not working very well.  It's using twice the CPU time that the EVR does for the same videos (more on this in the next question).

Since I've got the source, I decided to profile it to see what's going on.  (Among other things) this led me to:

```
HRESULT DX11VideoRenderer::CPresenter::CheckDeviceState(BOOL* pbDeviceChanged)
```

I'm not much of a DirectX expert (actually, I'm not one at all), but it seems likely that window handles can invalidate as monitors get unplugged, windows get FullScreened, closed, etc so a function like this makes perfect sense to me.

However.

When I look at the code for [CheckDeviceState](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/blob/340d6c8c537919663cb122d1a3cf76bed91c06f8/Samples/DX11VideoRenderer/cpp/Presenter.cpp#L851), the first thing it does is call SetVideoMonitor, which seems odd.

SetVideoMonitor looks like the routine you call when you first initialize the presenter (or change the target window), not something you'd call repeatedly to "Check" the device state.

Indeed, [SetVideoMonitor](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/blob/340d6c8c537919663cb122d1a3cf76bed91c06f8/Samples/DX11VideoRenderer/cpp/Presenter.cpp#L2091) calls TerminateDisplaySystem, followed by InitializeDisplaySystem.  I could see doing this once at startup, but those functions are being called *once per frame*.  That can't be right.

I can comment out the call to SetVideoMonitor in CheckDeviceState (or actually all of CheckDeviceState), and the code continues to function correctly (it's predictably a bit faster).  But then I'm not checking the device state anymore.

Trying to figure out the proper way to check for state changes in DX11 brought me [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/gaming/handling-device-lost-scenarios) which talks about just checking the return codes for  IDXGISwapChain::Present and ResizeBuffers.  Is that how this should be done?  Because that makes it seem like this whole routine is some leftover from DX9 (where it still would have been poorly implemented).

What's the correct way to check the device state in DX11?  Is this even a thing anymore?

Comment: I'd follow the DirectX11 article. Indeed that CheckDeviceState seems overkill. It's a pessimistic approach vs optimistic error checking. It's possible it won't change anything in the end (only a bit of less cpu usage) as it's not only a matter of pure speed, but rather a matter of syncing with the vblank

Comment: @SimonMourier Upon reflection, I think you're exactly right.  While sometimes MS writes articles about how things "should" work that don't reflect reality, this one seems correct.  The only 2 events I can think to worry about are 1) The window getting closed. 2) The window getting resized.  Things like moving the window to a new monitor, the monitor getting unplugged, etc aren't "my" problem.  The OS just handles it and the handle stays the same.  And it's pointless to check for #1, since it could change right after my check.  I'm still studying #2.

Comment: @SimonMourier The article talks about checking for DXGI_ERROR_DEVICE_REMOVED or DXGI_ERROR_DEVICE_RESET.  But I just tried moving a window onto a second monitor, then pulling the hdmi plug.  Present() never sent me an error.  Did the error get handled elsewhere and I just set the wrong breakpoint?  Or since the window just got dumped back on the primary monitor, I wonder if device removed/reset messages are being handled automatically now and I'll never get one?  Other than DestroyWindow(), how can I generate these errors?

Comment: Fire some game (or app but it's more difficult to find) that goes into (real/exclusive) full screen mode, and/or use in-game resolution change menu (depends on game of course). With two monitors, it can be even worse if primary screen is not the one where you run the game. This usually messes things good. In my case it can move my Visual Studio from the primary screen to the second automatically. It's kinda painful to restore all back, so use with caution...